# How to use AWS CodeArtifact within a local DockerFile

Tags: docker, aws-codeartifact

I set up AWS CodeArtifact for some of my projects. Every time I need to install packages I have to request a token for CodeArtifact and this lasts for about 12hrs. Locally on windows it works fine, but getting this to work on docker hasn't been successful yet.

The issue I am facing now is I have Docker set up locally on my machine, but the build keeps on failing. I get a 401 exception when I RUN yarn install in the Dockerfile.

Request failed "401 Unauthorized"".

What options do I have to resolve this? Not been able to find any documentation on this whatsoever.

I am new to docker, trying to get up and running.